# How to connect remote ssh server with socks proxy?

Tags: go, ssh, proxy

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

var (
    socks    string = "127.0.0.1:8000"
    server   string = "192.168.1.1:2222"
    cmd      string = ""
    login    string = "root"
    password string = ""
)

func main() {
    c, err := netConn(socks)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    conf := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: login,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(password),
        },
    }
    client, err := Dialer(conf, c, server)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    defer session.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    session.Run(cmd)
}

func netConn(addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to connect to %v", err))
    }
    return conn, nil
}

func Dialer(conf *ssh.ClientConfig, c net.Conn, host string) (*ssh.Client, error) {
    conn, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(c, host, conf)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return ssh.NewClient(conn, chans, reqs), nil
}
```

Client panic

> ssh: handshake failed: EOF
>
> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>
> [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x80f3e2d]
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>
> panic(0x8201b60, 0x18522030)
>
> /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x326
>
> golang.org/x/crypto/ssh.(*Client).NewSession(0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
>
> /home/user/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/client.go:129 +0xcd
>
> main.main()
>
> /home/user/go/src/ss/i.go:34 +0x276

And socks server in log

> [ERR] socks: Unsupported SOCKS version: [83]

How i can make it posible? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `x/net/proxy` package as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

func main() {

    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "user",
        // Auth: .... fill out with keys etc as normal
    }

    client, err := proxiedSSHClient("127.0.0.1:8000", "127.0.0.1:22", sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // get a session etc...
}

func proxiedSSHClient(proxyAddress, sshServerAddress string, sshConfig *ssh.ClientConfig) (*ssh.Client, error) {
    dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", proxyAddress, nil, proxy.Direct)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", sshServerAddress)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    c, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(conn, sshServerAddress, sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return ssh.NewClient(c, chans, reqs), nil
}
```

Comment: The above mentioned solution worked well. But you need to test it with proper SOCKS5 proxy.
Initially I got miss lead when testing it with some incorrect proxies (ex: simpleproxy), because it was not acting as a SOCKS5 proxy.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the ssh package API, the function

```
func Dial(network, addr string, config *ClientConfig) (*Client, error)
```

directly returns an object of type ssh.Client.
Therefore you can shorten a lot your code with:

```
func main() {
    conf := &ssh.ClientConfig{
            User: login,
            Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
                    ssh.Password(password),
            },
    }
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", server, conf)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    defer session.Close()
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
    }
    session.Run(cmd)
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: How it help connect with proxy?

Comment: sorry, i answered too quickly - my code was to connect directly to the ssh server not through a socks proxy.